# Failure to display metrics in Grafana's time series

Tags: grafana, trino, grafana-plugin

I use the following query (data source Trino) in Grafana 9, but in the timeseries, only the “value” values are displayed and the “metric” values are not displayed, is this a bug in Grafana 9 for the Trino plugin?

```sql
 SELECT
  $__timeGroup(FETCH_DATE, '1d'),
  SUM(ROWS_INSERTED) as value,
  task_name as metric
FROM
  zahraa.MONITORING
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(FETCH_DATE) 
GROUP BY $__timeGroup(FETCH_DATE, '1d'), task_name, STATUS
order by $__timeGroup(FETCH_DATE, '1d'), task_name, STATUS
```

Comment: What do you mean by '“metric” values are not displayed' exactly? Also what panel is in use, and what does table view shows?

Comment: it is displayed in three columns in tabular mode, FETCH_DATE, value, and metric. but in timeseries visualization, The task _name is not displayed